# Using Quartz.NET in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cmd, orchardcms, scheduler, quartz.net

I'm building a Orchard CMS website project and I need schedule to do some jobs which data are stored in database recurrently, so I use Quartz.NET in Global.asax of Orchard.Web as follows:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    _starter = new Starter<IOrchardHost>(HostInitialization, HostBeginRequest, HostEndRequest);
    _starter.OnApplicationStart(this);

    ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();

    // get a scheduler
    IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();
    sched.Start();

    var job = JobBuilder.Create<JobWorker>()
    .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
    .Build();

    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .StartAt(DateTime.Now)
    .WithCronSchedule("5 0/1 * * * ?")
    .Build();

    sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

And JobWorker class - is placed at the same level folder as Global.asax in Orchard.Web:

```
public class JobWorker : IJob, IDependency {
    private readonly ISchedulerService _schedulerService;

    public JobWorker (ISchedulerService schedulerService) {
        _schedulerService = schedulerService;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) {
        _schedulerService.ExecuteJob();

    }
}
```

However, I've received results in debug output console as follows:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Quartz.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Quartz.SchedulerException' occurred in Quartz.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Quartz.SchedulerException' occurred in Quartz.dll
The thread '<No Name>' (0x2278) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x3368) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x22a8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x2bc8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I've tried using this code in a web mvc 4 project - not orchard - and it worked OK. Therefore, I think the problem is at Orchard CMS.
What should I do ? I only need a timer to call method ExecuteJob() in SchedulerService recurrently !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about how you could get Quartz.NET working in Orchard but Orchard has its own services for dealing with recurring and/or scheduled background tasks.

Look at implementing IBackgroundTask ([sample](https://orchardtrainingdemo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Services/BackgroundTask.cs)) for simple recurring tasks and IScheduledTaskHandler ([sample](https://orchardtrainingdemo.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Services/ScheduledTask.cs)) for more sophisticatedly timed recurring tasks or scheduled one-time tasks.

Comment: Wow, it's really more simple than using Quartz.NET :)